# Does TcpClient check packets have been received?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have written a program for internal use at my company that sends and receives files using the TCPclient and TcpListener classes within .Net, and I just want to know whether this class automatically checks that packets have been received or if I have to write my own method for checking this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP itself will detect (and try to re-request) packets that go *missing*, and fix ordering, so you shouldn't need to deal with *those* things; however, that doesn't mean that everything will arrive (sometimes sockets simply break, and sometimes someone trips over a network cable and yanks it out of the machine); if you need an acknowledgement that the other end has received data, the only reliable way to do that is for the other end to *send a response message*. Of course, then you get into the scenario where the other end thinks it sent a response and *you don't get that response*, because someone cut the wrong wire. Lack of a response doesn't mean that the target server didn't receive and process the message!